# How to consequently change letter using javascript with a second delay using setTimeout?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a text display in DOM from a->b->c->d->e with a 1-second delay between each alphabet using setTimeout. However, the result came out as letter changing from 'a' an immediately to 'e' without displaying 'b' 'c' 'd'. However, all the letters are displayed in the console without having 1-second delay. Sorry for my confusing explanation.

```js
function changeLetter() {
  const symbols = ['Ai', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
  let symbol
  for (let i = 0; i < symbols.length; i++) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      symbol = symbols[i]
      console.log(symbol)
      document.getElementById("change").innerHTML = symbol;
    }, 1000)
  }
}
changeLetter()
```

```html
<h1 id="change"></h1>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the entire for loop runs before the first timeout can fire.

An elegant way to handle this is to call the function from the timeout itself. This way the next timeout doesn't begin until the previous has finished (this uses `% symbols.length` to make it loop continuously):

```js
const symbols = ['Ai', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

function changeLetter(i) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        symbol = symbols[i]
        document.getElementById("change").innerHTML = symbols[i];
        changeLetter((i+1) % symbols.length) 
    }, 1000)
}


changeLetter(0)
```

```html
<h1 id="change"></h1>
```

Alternatively, you could just use `setInterval`

```js
const symbols = ['Ai', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
count = 0
let inthandle = setInterval(() => {
  document.getElementById("change").innerHTML = symbols[count];
  count = (count + 1) % symbols.length
}, 1000)
```

```html
<h1 id="change"></h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is happening as all the `setTimeout()` calls are registered at 1000 ms and overlapped, so you see the transition to `d` happening instantaneously and hence skipping the elements in between.

You need to register the `setTimeout()` for the next elements consecutively. So simply `1000 * (i + 1)` will do this in the `setTimeout` call. For the first element it will be 1000 ms, the next will be at 2000 ms and so on.

```js
function changeLetter() {
  const symbols = ['Ai', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
  let symbol
  for (let i = 0; i < symbols.length; i++) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      symbol = symbols[i]
      console.log(symbol)
      document.getElementById("change").innerHTML = symbol;
    }, 1000 * (i + 1))
  }
}
changeLetter()
```

```html
<h1 id="change"></h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your for loop executes immediately. So you're instantiating 5 `setTimeout` calls simultaneously, which all execute at the same time. Since the last `setTimeout`'s callback changes the value to `d`, you're seeing that immediately.

Instead, you'll want to recursively delay calling each `setTimeout` until the previous one completed. Something like this:

```
const symbols = ['a','b','c'];
const currentSymbol = 0;

function changeLetter() {
  if (currentSymbol < symbols.length) {
    document.getElementById("change").innerHTML = symbols[currentSymbol];
    currentSymbol++;
    setTimeout(changeLetter, 1000);
  }
}
```